# Android addView cause Crash Without any Log

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, typeface

When I call addView about 80 times ,app will close automatically, how can i fix it?

MainActivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
            l.addView(new MyTextView(this));
        setContentView(l);
    }
```

MyTextView

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/default.ttf"));
        setTextSize(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: As per your code, your `addView` is not called over 80 times - `i < 80`.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the case, but sometimes in some situations Thread.sleep(x); helps. Try to add it in a loop after  l.addView(new MyTextView(this));

Comment: @Marek did you just suggest to call `sleep()` on the `Main Thread`? This is ok on a background `Thread` but not on the `UI Thread`

Comment: @neo108 I means call it much times, and you're right.

Comment: Have you check that you have the font resources you are trying to use?
I am not saying your code is correct or not, but it should run. Except if you are missing the fonts resources you are trying to use. remove the setTypeface line and run it.

Comment: @soynerdito i've already checked the resources , it can run if just call it several times, but too much will close automatically,if remove the setTypeface line is fine, but how can i keep the setTypeface and running?

Comment: try this
setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/default.ttf"));
Using the applicationContext instead of the regular Context

Comment: Or you may try
TextView tv;
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), 
"fonts/default.ttf");

        for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++){

         tv = new MyTextView(this);

         tv.setTypeface(tf);

         l.addView(tv);

        }

Comment: i think i've found the broblem, call Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/default.ttf") too often will make the app close.